# VBA HTML Pull Needs to Be Sped Up

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I have the following code that works (thank you all for your help!), but it runs relatively slow. It takes about 20-25min to run through roughly 1000 links.

This is a little long to be utilized effectively (although I understand opening and scraping 1000 listings takes time) - is there any way to shorten this?

Ideally, I'd like to pull info from over 10K links.

```
Public Sub ListingInfo()
Dim cell As Range
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("eBayListings")
    For Each cell In .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp))
        Dim Document As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
        Dim elem As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
        Dim elem2 As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
        With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
            .Open "GET", cell.Value, False
            .send
            Set Document = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
            Document.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        End With
        Set elem2 = Document.getElementById("itemTitle")
        If Not elem2 Is Nothing Then
        cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = elem2.innerText
        Else
        End If
        Set elem2 = Document.getElementById("vi-cdown_timeLeft")
        If Not elem2 Is Nothing Then
        cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = elem2.innerText
        Else
        End If
        Set elem = Document.getElementById("prcIsum_bidPrice")
        If Not elem Is Nothing Then
        cell.Offset(0, 3).Value = elem.innerText
        Else
        End If
        Set elem = Document.getElementById("prcIsum")
        If Not elem Is Nothing Then
        cell.Offset(0, 4).Value = elem.innerText
        Else
        End If
        Set elem2 = Document.getElementById("mbgLink")
        If Not elem2 Is Nothing Then
        cell.Offset(0, 5).Value = elem2.innerText
        Else
        End If
        Set elem2 = Document.getElementById("si-fb")
        If Not elem2 Is Nothing Then
        cell.Offset(0, 6).Value = elem2.innerText
        Else
        End If
        Set elem2 = Document.getElementById("binBtn_btn")
        If Not elem2 Is Nothing Then
        cell.Offset(0, 7).Value = elem2.innerText
        Else
        End If
        Set elem2 = Document.getElementById(".ds_div")
        If Not elem2 Is Nothing Then
        cell.Offset(0, 8).Value = elem2.innerText
        Else
        End If
        If Not Document.querySelector(".viSNotesCnt") Is Nothing Then
            cell.Offset(0, 9).Value = Document.querySelector(".viSNotesCnt").innerText
        Else
            'Try Something Else
        End If
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you do some timing to find out where the most time is spent?  Most likely it's in getting the response to your Get request, so there may not be much you can do.  it's also possible you're being throttled if you're making too many requests in a short time.

Comment: If you are going to be doing this a lot, use eBay's API. See --> https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/shopping/docs/CallRef/GetSingleItem.html

Answer (score 2):

The comment regarding throttling is an important one. You may need to add some waits in. One technique can be to maintain a count of urls visited and every x number introduce a wait.

For the above, you can shave off some time by avoiding hitting the sheet each time to access values and write out. Instead, store urls in an array and loop that. Stores results each run through loop into an array. Write entire results array out in one go at end.

Move xmlhttp object creation out of loop. Switch of screen-updating and any other application/sheet optimization you desire.

Potentially reduce your lines of code as shown below.

You might wish to add a test in case only one url present in sheet in which case you would need to redim the urls array to prevent an error and simply assign direct from populated cell to array.

**Not tested.**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub ListingInfo()
    Dim Document As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, urls(), url As String, results()
    Set Document = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("eBayListings")
        urls = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value
        ReDim results(1 To UBound(urls, 1), 1 To 9)
        With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
            For url = LBound(urls, 1) To UBound(urls, 1)
                .Open "GET", urls(url), False
                .send
                Document.body.innerHTML = .responseText
                On Error Resume Next
                With Document
                    results(url, 1) = .getElementById("itemTitle").innerText
                    results(url, 2) = .getElementById("vi-cdown_timeLeft").innerText
                    results(url, 3) = .getElementById("prcIsum_bidPrice").innerText
                    results(url, 4) = .getElementById("prcIsum").innerText
                    results(url, 5) = .getElementById("mbgLink").innerText
                    results(url, 6) = .getElementById("si-fb").innerText
                    results(url, 7) = .getElementById("binBtn_btn").innerText
                    results(url, 8) = .getElementById(".ds_div").innerText '<== is this id correct
                    results(url, 9) = .querySelector(".viSNotesCnt").innerText
                    'any tests on current row (url) for empty.......
                End With
                On Error GoTo 0
            Next
        End With
        .Cells(1, 2).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```